# Match Meteor collection based on array of values

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

Suppose I have a list of IDs I want to filter a Collection by:

```
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

How do I filter the collection to match just those IDs? Something like this doesn't work:

```
return Coll.fetch({_id: {$all: ids}});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
return Collection.find({_id: {$in: ids}}).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might approach this:

```js
function hasAllIds(collections, ids) {
  for (let i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
    let count = collections[i].find({
      _id: {
        $in: ids
      }
    }).count();
    if (count === ids.length) {
      return collections[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

const colls = [Meteor.users, Games]; //etc.
const ids = [1, 2, 3];
const coll = hasAllIds(colls, ids);
if (coll) {
  coll.find(); //or whatever
}
```